# master selector SAP Dashboards (Xcelsius)

Tags: dashboard, xcelsius

I am working on a SAP Dashboards project that requires a selector (combo box) that filters multiple charts on a dashboard. For example there are "Store" details and then several charts that repeat Store with other measures - i.e. a chart for "Store, Revenue", "Store, average sales per day" "Store, "Revenue by month".

I get the concept of a selector but only know how to build one for individual charts. Is there a way to have one "master" selector of that chooses "Store" and then filters the multiple charts, i.e. showing me Revenue, Rev by month, Average sales per day.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is Dashboards 4.0

Comment: If your data is arranged in such a way that Store is common then one filter will help. In Other ways create multiple combo box filters and use the option of Insert Selected Item in "Behaviour" Tab and hide the combo boxes one behind the other.